# TypeScript: define array type of unknown size where first element is of type A and rest elements are of type B

Tags: arrays, typescript-typings

I have a function that merges element of type `A` with some array of elements of type `B`.

The function arguments would be something like `function merge<A, B>(elem: A, ar: B[])`.
The result could be something like `[A, B, B, B, ..., B]`. The number of B elements and thus the total array length is unknown.

I know I could define a type like `Array<A | B>` but this wouldn't give complete type safety cuz any element could be either `A` or `B`. I also know that I can define types like `[A, B]`, `[A, B, B]` and so on. But as I understand, those could only be used for arrays of known sizes.

Is there a way to define a type like `[A, B, B, B, ..., B]` in TypeScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, found an answer to this. In typescript starting from version 3 you can define destructuring types like `[A, ...[B]]` which will give the desired result.

You might also have to cast the return statement `as [A, ...[B]]` to avoid type errors.